# Create Firebase Project using Terraform

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I would like to crate Firebase projects using Terraform.

Based on the GCP Terraform Provider documentation I have created some Terraform modules, but the Terraform apply call fails with

> Error 403: The caller does not have permission

What permissions are needed for the Terraform Service Account to be able to manage the Firebase projects?

I would like to create the following resources using a Terraform Service Account:

- google_firebase_project
- google_firebase_project_location
- google_firebase_web_app
- google_firebase_web_app_config
- google_storage_bucket
- google_storage_bucket_object

Comment: Can you also share your `tf` file and a screenshot of complete error (if there is some more information printed in the console)? Also you did activate the service account created for terraform right and not just using default credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Steps can help you in resolving Error 403: The caller does not have permission :

- You are missing to provide service account authorization to Terraform
  which is the source of the error message and you need give this
  permission :   `resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy`
- Use below To list the roles assigned to the service account:
  `gcloud projects get-iam-policy <YOUR GCLOUD PROJECT ID> \ --flatten="bindings[].members" \ --format='table(bindings.role)' \ --filter="bindings.members:<YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT>"`
- Use below To list the permissions that a role contains:
  `gcloud iam roles describe roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin`
- Use below To add the required role to the service account:
  `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <YOUR GCLOUD PROJECT ID> \ --member=serviceAccount:<YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT> \ --role=roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin`

Refer to this [IAM Policy service account terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account_iam) for more information.
As you need to create other resources, in the above doc, click on the right side at the respective module for more information.